Running a pre-built artefact in azure yaml pipeline
We have a Yaml process that publishes a pipeline artifact, this work as expected.
We also have a batch of Yaml files which use this artifact to run selenium tests, these also work as expected.
The test Yaml files have the following values included,
definitionId: 55
pipelineId: 66666

These were taken from the artifact build report but we assume that when make changes to the artifact and re-create it the values may well change which means we will have to update the test Yaml files.
Or do we? Is there a method for storing these values as artifacts/peristed variables when the artifact is recreated and then have the test Yaml's read them in at run time?
Thanks in advance for any advise.
